# Is there a way to automate similar (almost repetitive) code and make it like a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic

Here is the code: it's may not make a lot of sense as such but my question isn't so much to do with syntax.

Essentially ... there are upto 7 images and it arranges in predefined layouts and other stuff ... how do i make this repetitive, non expandable code more streamlined?

```
im1 = None
im2 = None
im3 = None
im4 = None
im5 = None
im6 = None
im7 = None

if com == 2:
#    cv2.imshow("")
    layout = int(input("Enter layout number: "))
    im1 = im_1()
    im2 = im_2()
    while (im1 == im2):
        print("Invalid")
        im1 = im_1()
        im2 = im_2()
elif com == 3:
#    cv2.imshow("")
    layout = int(input("Enter layout number: "))
    im1 = im_1()
    im2 = im_2()
    im3 = im_3()
    while (im1 == im2) | (im1 == im3) | (im2 == im3):
        print("Invalid")
        im1 = im_1()
        im2 = im_2()
        im3 = im_3()
elif com == 4:
#    cv2.imshow("")
    layout = int(input("Enter layout number: "))
    im1 = im_1()
    im2 = im_2()
    im3 = im_3()
    im4 = im_4()
    while (im1 == im2) | (im1 == im3) | (im1 == im4) | (im2 == im3) | (im2 == im4) | (im3 == im4):
        print("Invalid")
        im1 = im_1()
        im2 = im_2()
        im3 = im_3()
        im4 = im_4()
elif com == 5:
#    cv2.imshow("Layouts: 5", l5)
    layout = int(input("Enter layout number: "))
    im1 = im_1()
    im2 = im_2()
    im3 = im_3()
    im4 = im_4()
    im5 = im_5()
    while (im1 == im2) | (im1 == im3) | (im1 == im4) | (im1 == im5) | (im2 == im3) | (im2 == im4) | (im2 == im5) | (im3 == im4) | (im3 == im5) | (im4 == im5):
        print("Invalid")
        im1 = im_1()
        im2 = im_2()
        im3 = im_3()
        im4 = im_4()
        im5 = im_5()
elif com == 6:
#    cv2.imshow("")
    layout = int(input("Enter layout number: "))
    im1 = im_1()
    im2 = im_2()
    im3 = im_3()
    im4 = im_4()
    im5 = im_5()
    im6 = im_6()
    while (im1 == im2) | (im1 == im3) | (im1 == im4) | (im1 == im5) | (im1 == im6) | (im2 == im3) | (im2 == im4) | (im2 == im5) | (im2 == im6) | (im3 == im4) | (im3 == im5) | (im3 == im6) | (im4 == im5) | (im4 == im6) | (im5 == im6):
        print("Invalid")
        im1 = im_1()
        im2 = im_2()
        im3 = im_3()
        im4 = im_4()
        im5 = im_5()
        im6 = im_6()
elif com == 7:
#    cv2.imshow("")
    layout = int(input("Enter layout number: "))
    im1 = im_1()
    im2 = im_2()
    im3 = im_3()
    im4 = im_4()
    im5 = im_5()
    im6 = im_6()
    im7 = im_7()
    while (im1 == im2) | (im1 == im3) | (im1 == im4) | (im1 == im5) | (im1 == im6) | (im1 == im7) | (im2 == im3) | (im2 == im4) | (im2 == im5) | (im2 == im6) | (im2 == im7) | (im3 == im4) | (im3 == im5) | (im3 == im6) | (im3 == im7) | (im4 == im5) | (im4 == im6) | (im4 == im7) | (im5 == im6) | (im5 == im7) | (im6 == im7):
        print("Invalid")
        im1 = im_1()
        im2 = im_2()
        im3 = im_3()
        im4 = im_4()
        im5 = im_5()
        im6 = im_6()
        im7 = im_7()
```

It's a computer vision code that compares images, but rn it only works up to 7 because i have to predefine the images before hand. `com` is actually user inputed and if it is < 7 ... memory is still used as 7 images are defined, and it doesn't allow `com` to be >7.

Also, if you see, it only works till 7 as the image comparison hasn't been hardcoded for >7. But the logic for `com` = n is very easy to hardcode but just laborious. Is there a way to make this code for n images/terms where it defines the exact number of variables and self right the comparison/layout section for `com` = n?

Similarly, can we extend that to this:

```
if i != 0:
                if i == 1:
                    anim1 = cv2.imread("anim_1.jpg")
                    border_b = cv2.copyMakeBorder(anim1, bt, bt, bt, bt, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value = c_b)
                    border_w = cv2.copyMakeBorder(border_b, wt, wt, wt, wt, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value = c_w)
                    anim1 = border_w
                if i == 2:
                    anim2 = cv2.imread("anim_2.jpg")
                    border_b = cv2.copyMakeBorder(anim2, bt, bt, bt, bt, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value = c_b)
                    border_w = cv2.copyMakeBorder(border_b, wt, wt, wt, wt, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value = c_w)
                    anim2 = border_w
                if i == 3:
                    anim3 = cv2.imread("anim_3.jpg")
                    border_b = cv2.copyMakeBorder(anim3, bt, bt, bt, bt, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value = c_b)
                    border_w = cv2.copyMakeBorder(border_b, wt, wt, wt, wt, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value = c_w)
                    anim3 = border_w
                if i == 4:
                    anim4 = cv2.imread("anim_4.jpg")
                    border_b = cv2.copyMakeBorder(anim4, bt, bt, bt, bt, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value = c_b)
                    border_w = cv2.copyMakeBorder(border_b, wt, wt, wt, wt, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value = c_w)
                    anim4 = border_w
                if i == 5:
                    anim5 = cv2.imread("anim_5.jpg")
                    border_b = cv2.copyMakeBorder(anim5, bt, bt, bt, bt, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value = c_b)
                    border_w = cv2.copyMakeBorder(border_b, wt, wt, wt, wt, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value = c_w)
                    anim5 = border_w
                if i == 6:
                    anim6 = cv2.imread("anim_6.jpg")
                    border_b = cv2.copyMakeBorder(anim6, bt, bt, bt, bt, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value = c_b)
                    border_w = cv2.copyMakeBorder(border_b, wt, wt, wt, wt, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value = c_w)
                    anim6 = border_w
                if i == 7:
                    anim7 = cv2.imread("anim_7.jpg")
                    border_b = cv2.copyMakeBorder(anim7, bt, bt, bt, bt, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value = c_b)
                    border_w = cv2.copyMakeBorder(border_b, wt, wt, wt, wt, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value = c_w)
                    anim7 = border_w
```

and

```
if com == 2:
    if im1 == 1:
        im1 = anim1
        im2 = anim2
    elif im1 == 2:
        im1 = anim2
        im2 = anim1
elif com == 3:
    if (im1 == 1) | (im1 == 2) | (im1 == 3):
        if im1 == 1:
            im1 = anim1
        elif im1 == 2:
            im1 = anim2
        elif im1 == 3:
            im1 = anim3
    if (im2 == 1) | (im2 == 2) | (im2 == 3):
        if im2 == 1:
            im2 = anim1
        elif im2 == 2:
            im2 = anim2
        elif im2 == 3:
            im2 = anim3
    if (im3 == 1) | (im3 == 2) | (im3 == 3):
        if im3 == 1:
            im3 = anim1
        elif im3 == 2:
            im3 = anim2
        elif im3 == 3:
            im3 = anim3

//skipped till end of 7 because too repetitive.

elif com == 7:
    if (im1 == 1) | (im1 == 2) | (im1 == 3) | (im1 == 4) | (im1 == 5) | (im1 == 6) | (im1 == 7):
        if im1 == 1:
            im1 = anim1
        elif im1 == 2:
            im1 = anim2
        elif im1 == 3:
            im1 = anim3
        elif im1 == 4:
            im1 = anim4
        elif im1 == 5:
            im1 = anim5
        elif im1 == 6:
            im1 = anim6
        elif im1 == 7:
            im1 = anim7
    if (im2 == 1) | (im2 == 2) | (im2 == 3) | (im2 == 4) | (im2 == 5) | (im2 == 6) | (im2 == 7):
        if im2 == 1:
            im2 = anim1
        elif im2 == 2:
            im2 = anim2
        elif im2 == 3:
            im2 = anim3
        elif im2 == 4:
            im2 = anim4
        elif im2 == 5:
            im2 = anim5
        elif im2 == 6:
            im2 = anim6
        elif im2 == 7:
            im2 = anim7
    if (im3 == 1) | (im3 == 2) | (im3 == 3) | (im3 == 4) | (im3 == 5) | (im3 == 6) | (im3 == 7):
        if im3 == 1:
            im3 = anim1
        elif im3 == 2:
            im3 = anim2
        elif im3 == 3:
            im3 = anim3
        elif im3 == 4:
            im3 = anim4
        elif im3 == 5:
            im3 = anim5
        elif im3 == 6:
            im3 = anim6
        elif im3 == 7:
            im3 = anim7
    if (im4 == 1) | (im4 == 2) | (im4 == 3) | (im4 == 4) | (im4 == 5) | (im4 == 6) | (im4 == 7):
        if im4 == 1:
            im4 = anim1
        elif im4 == 2:
            im4 = anim2
        elif im4 == 3:
            im4 = anim3
        elif im4 == 4:
            im4 = anim4
        elif im4 == 5:
            im4 = anim5
        elif im4 == 6:
            im4 = anim6
        elif im4 == 7:
            im4 = anim7
    if (im5 == 1) | (im5 == 2) | (im5 == 3) | (im5 == 4) | (im5 == 5) | (im5 == 6) | (im5 == 7):
        if im5 == 1:
            im5 = anim1
        elif im5 == 2:
            im5 = anim2
        elif im5 == 3:
            im5 = anim3
        elif im5 == 4:
            im5 = anim4
        elif im5 == 5:
            im5 = anim5
        elif im5 == 6:
            im5 = anim6
        elif im5 == 7:
            im5 = anim7
    if (im6 == 1) | (im6 == 2) | (im6 == 3) | (im6 == 4) | (im6 == 5) | (im6 == 6) | (im6 == 7):
        if im6 == 1:
            im6 = anim1
        elif im6 == 2:
            im6 = anim2
        elif im6 == 3:
            im6 = anim3
        elif im6 == 4:
            im6 = anim4
        elif im6 == 5:
            im6 = anim5
        elif im6 == 6:
            im6 = anim6
        elif im6 == 7:
            im6 = anim7
    if (im7 == 1) | (im7 == 2) | (im7 == 3) | (im7 == 4) | (im7 == 5) | (im7 == 6) | (im7 == 7):
        if im7 == 1:
            im7 = anim1
        elif im7 == 2:
            im7 = anim2
        elif im7 == 3:
            im7 = anim3
        elif im7 == 4:
            im7 = anim4
        elif im7 == 5:
            im7 = anim5
        elif im7 == 6:
            im7 = anim6
        elif im7 == 7:
            im7 = anim7
```

tl;dr: how do i make this unnecessarily repetitive code more streamlined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first piece of code could use a function to get rid of the nasty boolean logic and arrays and loops to get rid of the hardcoded variables.

```
# Replaces im1 - im7
im_values = []
for i in range(7):
    im_values.append(None)

# Map functions to array
im_functions = []
im_functions.append(im_1)
im_functions.append(im_2)
im_functions.append(im_3)
im_functions.append(im_4)
im_functions.append(im_5)
im_functions.append(im_6)
im_functions.append(im_7)

# Checks the long if-tests in your code, a helper function
def any_equal(n):
    for i in range(n-1):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            if (im_values[i] == im_values[j]):
                return True
    return False

# All hardcoded if tests are replaced with a for loop
#    cv2.imshow("")
layout = int(input("Enter layout number: "))
for i in range(com):
    im_values[i] = im_functions[i]()
    while(any_equal(com)):
        print("Invalid")
        for j in range(com):
            im_values[j] = im_functions[j]()
```

The second part of the code looks like it could be replaced with a simple function.

```
anims = []
for i in range(7):
    anims.append(None)

def load_anim(img):
    anim = cv2.imread(img)
    border_b = cv2.copyMakeBorder(anim, bt, bt, bt, bt, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value = c_b)
    border_w = cv2.copyMakeBorder(border_b, wt, wt, wt, wt, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value = c_w)
    return border_w

if i != 0:
    anims[i-1] = load_anim(f"anim_{i}.jpg")
```

The third part looks similar, just use arrays and loops and you should get it done. I leave that for you to solve yourself, it shouldn't be too hard hopefully :)

Answer (score 0):

**Code block 1:**

See if you can only define things when you need them

**Code block 2:**

```
"anim_"+i+".jpg"
```

**Code block 3:**

```
if im1 == 1) | (im1 == 2) ... | (im1 == 7):
```

should just be

```
if im1 <= 7:
```

For the long elif chains, use a list

```
Anim = [anim0, anim1, anim2]
im1 = Anim[0]
```

I think you would save time learning more of the basics before creating large projects

```
# example code 

TmpLayout1 = [[1,0],[0,1]]
TmpLayout2 = [[0,1],[0,1]]
ImageLayouts = [TmpLayout1, TmpLayout2]
```

Comment: yeah but the main thing about this is it still requires hardcoding ... is there a way to create some mapping framework of some sort?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you should be able to use arrays and operate on them without hardcoding anything. If you are arranging images in layouts, store the different layouts in arrays and then place the images based on that. From what I'm seeing I'm assuming you have hardcoded layouts with if statements.